# php while rows closing on another id

Tags: php, mysql

I have my php that prints out a bunch of rows from `mysql` database. It looks like this:

http://prntscr.com/7dafb9

If I click `close ticket` on the top row, it will always close the last row id, because it was the last id put in the row and I have no idea what's wrong with my code. Here it is:

```html
 <?php 
   $sql = "SELECT id,name,server,issue,title,open FROM tickets WHERE open='1' ORDER by time";
   $result = $configconn->query($sql);
        
     if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $ticketid = $row["id"];
         $ticketopen = $row["open"];
         $ticketserver = $row["server"];
         $ticketissue = $row["issue"];
         $tickettitle = $row["title"];
         $ticketname = $row["name"];

         if($ticketopen == 1) {
           $open = '<span class="label label-success label-mini">Open ID:'.$ticketid.'</span>';
         } else {
           $open = '<span class="label label-danger label-mini">Closed ID:'.$ticketid.'</span>';
         }

         echo ' <tr>
           <td>'.$open.'</td>
           <td class="hidden-phone">'.$ticketissue.'</td>
           <td>'.$tickettitle.' </td>
           <td><span class="label label-info label-mini">'.$ticketserver.'</span></td>
           <td>'.$ticketname.' </td>

           <form action="openedtickets.php" method="POST">
             <td>       
               <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">Close Ticket</button>       
             </td>
           </form>
         </tr>';
         
       }
     } else {
       Echo '<center><div class="alert alert-success">There are no open Tickets!</div></center>';
     }
   ?>

   <?php

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       if($_SESSION['power'] >= 1){
         $sql = "UPDATE tickets SET open='0' WHERE id='$ticketid'";
         if (mysqli_query($configconn, $sql)) {
           $sollved = $_SESSION['ticketssolved'] + 1; 
           $sql2 = "UPDATE users SET ticketssolved='$sollved' WHERE user='$user'"; 
           mysqli_query($configconn, $sql2);
           
           $closedby = $_SESSION['username']; 
           $sql3 = "UPDATE tickets SET closedticket='$closedby' WHERE id='$ticketid'"; 
           mysqli_query($configconn, $sql3);
           header("Location: openedtickets.php");

         } else {

           Echo '<center><div class="alert alert-danger">Ticket ID:'.$ticketid.' Failed to Close!</div></center>';
            
         }
       } else {

       Echo '<center><div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry you need to be Trial Mod or Higher!</div></center>';

     }
         
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: Looking at the provided code, it doesn't look like you pass the ticket ID at all when you click close ticket...

Comment: i think it gets the id of the last ticket, because when i click the close ticket on the first button, it ALWAYS closes the last one in the row, and not the one i click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="openedtickets.php" method="POST">
    <td>
        <input type='hidden' name='ticketid' value="<?php echo $ticketid; ?>" />
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">Close Ticket</button>

    </td>
</form>
```

Comment: i tried this, but it still closed the Last one in the row :/